# Event, delegate or interface?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a **Monkey** class which sometimes needs to acquire an instance  of **Banana**. The way this banana is provided is not of interest to the monkey, but it does initiate the banana acquisition.

Now I have at least three possible ways to wire my monkey to a banana provider. **What is the best way to do it?**

**1. Event**

Raise a `Monkey.BananaNeeded` event. The event handler sets the `BananaNeededEventArgs.Banana` property.

**2. Interface**

Invoke `IBananaProvider.GetBanana`. The `IBananaProvider` instance is injected in the monkey as a constructor argument or through a property.

**3. Delegate**

Invoke a delegate of type [`System.Func<Banana>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx). The delegate is injected in the monkey as a constructor argument or through a property. This one is tempting because it doesn't require the declaration of any extra interfaces or classes, but apparently it is not a popular choice.

Comment: +1 for amusing examples and a decent question, but of course the monkey doesn't care it acquires a banana, all it cares for is munching on a tasty treat.

Comment: Fat monkey: while(true) _provider.GetBanana.Eat();

Comment: Don't forget to dispose of the banana skins.  We don't want a banana skin leak on our hands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't like the event and delegate options unless there is a mechanism to ensure multiple handlers won't be attached.  Option 2 is therefore the winner, IMO.

Comment: You can't attach more than one method to a delegate...

Comment: @Guffa - Eh? All delegates in .NET are MulticastDelegate, and the whole point is that you *can* attach multiple methods to it. How do you think events work??

Comment: Yes, you can combine the delegates, but it's totally useless in this case as only the last one can return the banana.

Answer (score 4):

The event model works best if there is several possible banana providers, i.e. the monkey asks all providers in turn for a banana, and the first one that can provide one gets to deliver it.

The other two models work fine for a single banana prover per monkey. The delegate is easier to create a provider for, and the interface is more structured.

Answer (score 1):

The best way in the above scenario is to go for Interface. In OOAD terms we can define the above scenario as Monkey class has a Banana.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the 2.

```
IBananaProvider bananaProvider = ProviderFactory.Get<IBananaProvider>();
```

Comment: +1 ...but then doesn't the monkey need to know how to get to the factory to pick up his banana?

Comment: @Justin Niessner: sure,you can have a factory of Providerfactory based on an configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

There are operations on Monkey that make it require the Banana.

The need for the Monkey to get a Banana is du to these operations. You can surely pass the Banana as a parameter for the operations.

I will remove the dependency of the Money on a IBananaProvider.

```
class Monkey
{
   void FeedWith(Banana banana) { ... }
}
```

It will be the reponsibility of the caller to get the banana, not the Monkey.

I'm advocating here *not* to inject services in entities.

Comment: The monkey might need a new banana when he finishes the first one. :-)

Comment: In this case, pass the IBananaProvider as argument, the Monkey can decide how many bananas he wants.

Comment: But then again, Martin Fowler considers the Anemic Monkey Model to be an anti-pattern: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

Comment: I don't see why I would make the model anemic ? It's just that the IBananaProvider doesn't belong to Monkey's state.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally dependency injection is the more generally accepted approach.

Another approach to try is *message queues*.

In this scenario `Monkey` could essentially "post" a message to some queue for a delicious banana. This "posting" would trigger *some* provider who is monitoring the queue, to then fulfill the request - which actual instance of provider responds is irrelevant. `Monkey` would then wait for a response to the original message and take action when the parcel of interest arrives from the `BananaProvider`.

Message queues decouple providers and consumers. Granted, there is still some form of contract" in place, but *who* is on the other end of the request and answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree and say that option 2 is the best solution. Delegates are typically meant to, well delegate something, in other words do something, and events are meant for immediate response to something that happened, usually user-related. The interface simply says, "This is here and you can do it." Because you don't want the banana or the monkey doing anything at first and you don't want the user to be directly interacting with the inner workings of your code, an interface wins it. All you need is to know that the monkey can receive bananas. What he decides to do with those bananas afterwards is up to him, and the banana itself as well as the code surrounding should not concern itself with it.